# Realm Filter Issue

Tags: filter, realm, predicate

I have `Inventory Model` & `Stock Model` as realm object, whereby `Inventory` is to save as the product Category Name (eg. COKE / PEPSI ), and `Stock` as the product name (eg. Coke Regular, Coke Light, Coke Vanilla)

In my Parent Table, TableView are showing

- COKE -  **150** left
- PEPSI - **quantity** left

when `selectedRowAt` COKE, tableView will instantiate segue to another TableView called StockTable, which will show

- Coke Regular : 100 unit left
- Coke Light : 30 unit left
- Coke Vanilla : 20 unit left

Currently I have a button with 2 option when tapped at `ParentTable` :

1. to show all inventory with more than 1 quantity = **ISSUE**
2. to show all inventory without quantity count = **PERFORMING**

I am having issue to filter and query option 1, hence `"totalUnit"` is created with auto-update when perform `realm.write` to update `totalUnit` every single time, which is very risky for wrong information/data entry.

For me I want to query the data based on `StockModel's quantity`  `sum(property:"quantity")` instead of updating the `totalUnit` in `realm.write` as it will be very risky for future and to prevent bug.

So I had created two function

1. `showStockList_byTotalUnit() -> Results<StockModel>` **Currently Using**
2. `showStockList_byStockQuantity() -> [StockModel]`

which both are working accordingly to what I wanted to see as result, However, I am not sure using `[StockModel]` is the same as `Results<StockModel>` or not as all my other tableView are based on `Results<Object>?` instead of `Array`.

### Question

1. I want to remove `totalUnit` from `InventoryModel` and achieve ParentTable to show the total unit from its own `StockModel's quantity`
2. Can I convert `[StockModel]` to `Results<StockModel>`?
3. Is `showStockList_byStockQuantity` any issue that I might encounter?

```
class InventoryModel:Object {
    @objc dynamic var name:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var info:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var category:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var totalUnit:Int = 0 **THIS IS UPDATED BASED ON USER DELETE/ADD DATA, WISH TO REMOVE THIS**

   
    ///Childs
    var ofStock = List<StockModel>()
```

```
class StockModel:Object {
    @objc dynamic var name:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var quantity:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var purchasePrice:Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var totalCost:Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var purchaseDate:Date?
    
    ///Parent
    var parentInventory = LinkingObjects(fromType: InventoryModel.self, property: "ofStock")
```

```
**InventoryModel**

func showStockList_byTotalUnit() -> Results<StockModel>? {
        let showActiveStock = self.ofStock.sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true).distinct(by: ["name"]).filter("totalUnit > %@",0)
        return showActiveStock
        
    }
```

```
**Inventory Model**

    func showStockList_byStockQuantity() -> [StockModel] {
        let allStocks = self.ofStock.sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true).distinct(by: ["name"])
        var activeStocks:[StockModel] = []
        
        for stock in allStocks.enumerated() {
            let stockQuantity:Int = realm!.objects(StockModel.self).filter("name == %@", stock.element.name).sum(ofProperty: "quantity")
            
            if stockQuantity > 0 {
                activeStocks.append(stock.element)
            }
        }
        return activeStocks
    }
```

Comment: It's not really clear how your objects are related; the InventoryModel has a List of StockModel objects - meaning more than one - so there are 10 StockModel items within that list - are you trying to query a specific InventoryModel for items that have quantities or not? Also, we don't know what `selectedInventory` represents - is that a single InventoryModel? If so then the query you've indicated will return InventoryModel objects, not StockModel objects. Please clarify the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: I am trying to query for stock that have more than 1 quantity based by `selectedInventory`, user are actually get into the inventory to see the stocks items by distinct as user key in stock by FIFO method. so i want to query `activeStockList` that have more than 1 quantity only based on SUM total quantity for stock that match the stock name. `allStockList` performed well, however `activeStockList` are queried based on the transactions in realm.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still unclear. Are you stating the query for `allStockList` is working correctly but the query for `activeStockList` is not? It's essentially the same query with a filter added to the latter. More importantly, if the first filter is working why not just add a `> 0` to the first results? e.g. `let result = allStockList.filter("quantity > 0")`

Comment: I had edited my question, feel free to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me shorten and repeat the question

> The objective is to get the qty of a particular InventoryModel based on the
> StockModel quantities stored in the ofStock list. (instead of storing
> it in InventoryModel totalUnit property).

Using the InventoryModel and StockModel in the question, if we create an inventory model for widget

```
let inv = InventoryModel()
inv.name = "Widget"
```

and then add two StockModel objects to its ofStock List

```
let sm0 = StockModel()
sm0.quantity = 1

let sm1 = StockModel()
sm1.quantity = 2

inv.ofStock.append(objectsIn: [s0, s1])
```

If we then want to get the total inventory available for the Widget object, it's a single line

```
let sum: Int = realm.objects(StockModel.self).filter("ANY parentInventory.name == 'Widget'").sum(ofProperty: "quantity")
print(sum)
```

and the output is 3

Note that we are transversing back through the StockModels to get the parent they belong to.

**EDIT**

The OP also wanted to have a query to do the following (from the comments)

> I want to query for all InventoryModels that have ANY stock models
> that have a quantity > 0

Here's the query that returns all InventoryModel objects where any StockModels in the ofStock property have a quantity property greater than 0

```
let results = realm.objects(InventoryModel.self).filter("ANY ofStock.quantity > 0")
```

Comment: Your answer is good for `func showStockList_byTotalUnit() -> Results<StockModel>?` which sum up the output of quantity, but I am looking for Results<InventoryModel> that with more / zero quantity from Results<StockModel>

Comment: @JunyongYap I don't understand that part of the question. A single Inventory model can have multiple StockModels in its ofStock list. So you're looking for what specifically that has more than 0 quantity? Are you saying you want to return InventoryModels that have ANY stock models that have a quantity > 0?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to return inventory model that have any stock models that have quantity above 0

Comment: @JunyongYap Ok, I updated the answer to address that query as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn’t know that realm can filter it’s child’s as well. Will try it out !

Comment: @JunyongYap My pleasure. If it helps, please remember to accept it so it can help others.